# How to do an asynchronous counter using a function in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to do a counter from function and volley,
I'm doing a for loop on some data in web services, and when the data is the same with some data that I have, I want the counter to add 1, it is easy but when the function end and get back to the onCreate function the counter becomes 0, here is my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var n1 = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    Log.d("counter0", n1.toString())
    selectType()
    Log.d("counter2", n1.toString())

    carCount1.text= "$n1 cars "
}
}

fun selectType() {
    val url= "http://mydomen/getallcars.php"

    val pd= ProgressDialog(this)
    pd.setMessage("Please Wait...")
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER)
    pd.show()

    val rq= Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val sr= StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener { response ->
            pd.hide()

            //converting the string to json array object
            val array = JSONArray(response)

            list.clear()

            //traversing through all the object
            for (i in 0 until array.length()) {

                //getting item object from json array
                val product = array.getJSONObject(i)

                Log.d("testing123", product.toString())
                //adding the product to item list

                if(product.getString("type") == fandvtext.text.toString()) {
                    n1=+1

                    Log.d("counter1", n1.toString())

                }

                list.add(
                    Cars(
                        product.getString("type")
                    )
                )
            }

        },
        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            pd.hide()
            Toast.makeText(this, error.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        })
    Toast.makeText(this, n1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    rq.add(sr)
}
}

class Cars(types: String) {
    var types:String = types
}
```

then when I run it, in Logcat shows this

```
 D/counter0: 0
 D/counter1: 1
 D/counter2: 0
```

counter0 should be 0 and it is
and counter2 must be 1 and it not!!
so, now what do I have to do!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my template here : [How to get data from any asynchronous operation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android/57330767#57330767)

here's on thing you can do

change your function like this :

```
fun selectType(callback:(Int) -> Unit){ 
....
```

change this code to this :

```
fun selectType(callback:(Int) -> Unit) {
val url= "http://mydomen/getallcars.php"

val pd= ProgressDialog(this)
pd.setMessage("Please Wait...")
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER)
pd.show()

val rq= Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
val sr= StringRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, url,
    Response.Listener { response ->
        pd.hide()

        //converting the string to json array object
        val array = JSONArray(response)

        list.clear()

        //traversing through all the object
        var n1 = 0
        for (i in 0 until array.length()) {

            //getting item object from json array
            val product = array.getJSONObject(i)

            Log.d("testing123", product.toString())
            //adding the product to item list

            if(product.getString("type") == fandvtext.text.toString()) {
                n1=+1

                Log.d("counter1", n1.toString())

            }

            list.add(
                Cars(
                    product.getString("type")
                )
            )
        }
      callback.invoke(n1)
    },
```

then, where you call it in onCreate:

```
selectType(){ result -> 
//here, the result is the value of your count
}
```